# Bootstrap modal with drowdown menu responsive text

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, drop-down-menu

I have a bootstrap modal with a dropdown menu. However, the length of the text in the dropdown menu varies. Now if the screen is narrow (mobile) then part of the text is lost.I am very curious if it is possible to make the text responsive. So that drops the last part of the text. If this is not possible, is it then possible to visualize a vertical slider bar at the bottom if the text is not completely readable?

In this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/Pension007/y9bq1Lcw/17/) I made a model in which a dropdown menu is visible. The text is made extra long in the dropdown menu.

HTML

```
<html class="no-js">


  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.css" />

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <a class="btn color_orange_gradient" id="button" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicModal">
                    <i class="fas fa-sliders-h fa-lg"> Modal</i></a>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="basicModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header color_orange_gradient text-center">
            <h4 class="modal-title w-100 text-white" id="myModalLabel">Some data</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
        </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="extra-controls" id="debug">
              Dropdown menu
            </div>
            <select class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true">
  <option>Very long text needs to be shorten when in mobile view</option>
  <option>Very long text needs to be shorten when in mobile view</option>
  <option>Very long text needs to be shorten when in mobile view</option>
</select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
#shadow:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 11px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18), 0 4px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.color_orange_gradient {
  background: #f46b45;
  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #eea849, #f46b45);
  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #eea849, #f46b45);
  /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
}

.color_orange {
  background: #f46b45;
  /* fallback for old browsers */
}

.color_orange:hover {
  background-color: #f7977c !important;
}
```

Hopefully someone knows a solution to make the text readable.

Answer (score 1):

Try add this to your CSS sheet:

```
.dropdown-item{
  white-space : nowrap;
}
.dropdown-item .text {
  word-wrap:break-word;
}
.dropdown-menu.show{
  min-width:100%!important;
  width:100%!important;
}
```

Comment: Hi Hernandez, thanks for your response! I now indeed get a horizontal scrollbar but now the check mark falls over the text instead of at the end of the text. Do you happen to know a solution for this? I have modified the example above with your code here: https://jsfiddle.net/Pension007/y9bq1Lcw/

Comment: U need to stick in'n out with that CSS and you will acomplish your gold bruh!